# wcf events on client side

Tags: c#, wcf

Is theres a client side event in wcf which get fired every time I create the object of my wcf client.

Actually I want to add outgoing header under wcf client

for now I am using code below in my client constructor under `reference.cs`

```
private void AddCustomHeaderUserInformation(OperationContextScope scope)
{
    MessageHeader<int> mhg = new MessageHeader<int>(10);
    MessageHeader untyped = mhg.GetUntypedHeader("slash", "slash");
    OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(untyped);
}
```

There are two problems in using the above way

1. every time I update the client with wcf ,code vanishes and I need to write it again
2. code is suppose to be written in every client constructor, I am have 11 service contracts in my wcf.  so it really sucks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at implementing [IClient MessageInspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iclientmessageinspector.aspx) - this allows you to plug into the service model layer at a lower level - you would add your headers in BeforeSendRequest

Comment: Are you saying that the message inspector isn't getting executed?

Comment: yeah,i have used IDispatchMessageInspector, IClientMessageInspector no one get fired

Comment: do i need to add some thing under config file

Comment: IDispatchMessageInspector is for the service side. How were you wiring in your client message inspector?

Comment: The link I used describes how to plumb the client inspector into the client side using config

Comment: well i dont want to put any thing in config file as becoz every time i will update the service the config file get updated,

Comment: It doesn't rewrite the entire config file - just changes the pieces that it generated

Comment: its showing me error Invalid element in configuration. The extension 'clientInterceptors' does not derive from correct extension base type 'System.ServiceModel.Configuration.BehaviorExtensionElement' When i am creating the instance of client

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can create partial classes on the client side so that the behaviour is not lost every time you regenerate the client side code.